# Ubuntu server changes IP every night to "old" dhcp address

Tags: networking, ubuntu-12.04

I have a new installed Ubuntu 12.04.2 Server
After installation I changed */etc/network/interfaces* from **dhcp** to **static**.

After restarting "networking" everything works fine.
But every morning the IP is changed back to the old dhcp address.

Any ideas?

/etc/network/interfaces

```
# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.0.210
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.0.254
    dns-nameservers 192.168.0.254
```

/etc/resolv.conf

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 192.168.0.254
search localdomain
```

Lono

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK that is strange. You can start by trying to change your /etc/network/interfaces file

```
# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.0.210
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.0.254
```

You can start trying by removing the " dns-nameservers 192.168.0.254" because you are calling it in the /etc/resolv.conf file.

If this does not solve the problem you can try to alter the /etc/resolv.conf file and use a different dns(nameserver).

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

After this you might have to "lock" the /etc/resolv.conf file so the system won't change it. To do it simply type:

```
chattr +i /etc/resolv.conf
```

If you later wish to unlock the file simply type:

```
chattr -i /etc/resolv.conf
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I edited the post with the information you wanted

Comment: Try this steps. If this does not work it might have something to do with old DHCP leases.

Comment: I made this changes now. Let's see what happens tomorrow. Thanks

Comment: Long story short...
I had to restart that server in order to make the changes perstant